# Approaches for creating observation windows in a next-n-month regression model

Tags: regression, experiment-design

I am interested in predicting whether someone will post at least once on social media in the next, say, 6 months (so, setting this up as a binary classification task). I am trying to determine the optimal way of setting up my dataset to be able to best estimate a given individual's likelihood of posting at least once in the next 6 months, going forward.

Consider the following dataset:

| yearmonth | user_a_posted | user_b_posted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201901 | 0 | 0 |
| 201902 | 0 | 0 |
| 201903 | 0 | 0 |
| 201904 | 0 | 0 |
| 201905 | 0 | 0 |
| 201906 | 0 | 0 |
| 201907 | 0 | 0 |
| 201908 | 1 | 0 |
| 201909 | 0 | 0 |
| 201910 | 0 | 0 |
| 201911 | 0 | 0 |
| 201912 | 0 | 0 |
| 202001 | 0 | 0 |
| 202002 | 0 | 0 |
| 202003 | 0 | 0 |

where `user_{x}_posted` denotes whether the user posted at least once in the designated `yearmonth`.

There are three main approaches I can think of:

1. for each user, create *n*-number of rows, each representing next-6-month time windows. So for both of these users (each using the social media platform for 15 months), they'd have 15 - 6 = 9 rows – one for the period 201901-201907, another for 201902-201908, etc.
2. keep only one row for each individual, selecting some "anchor" point (e.g. 201901), observing the next 6 months, and recording whether the individual posted at all.
3. keep *n* number of rows for each user-post combination (so, a user posting *n* times would have *n* different positive cases in the dataset). For users never posting, randomly sample one 6-month time interval as their observation periods. This randomness, I think, would help the model to generalize across time periods.

The problem (I believe) with 1) is that users with longer tenure will be over-represented in the dataset, as a user on the platform for, say, 9 months will only have 3 rows. This *seems* problematic **as a lot of my potential features will not change over the observed time periods, and gives me pause as the model might more heavily weight the relevant attributes associated with longer-tenure members.** Additionally, any relevant signal from those "stagnant" features I fear will be drowned out as, outside of non-stagnant features (e.g. the number of likes in the last *n* months), there's no variance across time periods in these stagnant features in time periods when someone does and does *not* post - they are constant for each individual.

The problem with 2) is that the chosen anchor point is arbitrary – if I selected 201901 for all users, for example, we would "miss" the post user "a" made in 201908, simply because of the window chosen. Posting is an important indicator and to "miss" such an event is unfortunate. The only way I can think of to avoid this is to see whether someone posts at all, take one of the posting events (the first, for example), and simply use that month as the anchor point. That would only apply for those having posted – for those not having posted at all the period could be fixed for all or completely random.

I'm not quite sure what problems would exist with 3), but likely there would be some overlap w/ the problems of 1) of over-representation of certain individuals.

Any thoughts on how best to structure this problem? Notably, I plan to use/score with this model on a monthly basis, predicting whether someone will post in the next 6 months based off of various "stagnant" and rolling attributes.

Comment: Is your real data as sparse as the example? (I mean that there's just one 1)

Comment: @kastellane I assume you mean only one post? No – a user can post as much as they like. There will be users posting 0, 1, 2, ... times throughout my sample. But I'm really only interested in whether they'll post at least once in a given month.

Comment: More or less how many observations? Maybe used a mixed-effect model, with random intercepts for userID. That will represent the (probably) positive correlation within userID,